# CalendarViewDayItemChanging event doesn´t react?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a CalendarView in a Windows 10 Universal App. When the Day Item gets changed by the user, I want to open a ContentDialog. But this Code just doesn´t make anything. ContentDialog, StackPanel and TextBlock are of Course declared as global variables. Does anyone know why?

.xaml.cs

```
namespace SchlachterFliesen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Eine leere Seite, die eigenständig verwendet oder zu der innerhalb eines Rahmens navigiert werden kann.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Plan : Page
    {

        private TextBlock aufgaben;
        private ContentDialog dialog;
        private StackPanel panel;

        public Plan()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
            currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            currentView.BackRequested += backButton_Tapped; 
        }

        private void backButton_Tapped(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            var mainPage = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }


        private void aufgabenGeladen(Aufgabe[] antwort)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < antwort.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                aufgaben.Text += antwort[i].beschreibung;  
            }
        }

        private async void kalender_SelectedDatesChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            dialog = new ContentDialog();

            var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

            dialog.Title = "Am " + args.AddedDates[0].LocalDateTime.ToString() + " Sind Sie, " + Daten.LadeAktuellenBenutzer()?.mitarbeiter.vorname + " " + Daten.LadeAktuellenBenutzer()?.mitarbeiter.name + ", eingeteilt: ";
            dialog.MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth;



            panel = new StackPanel();


            aufgaben = new TextBlock();
            aufgaben.Text = "Sie haben an diesem Tag folgendes zu tun:\n";
            aufgaben.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

            //Daten.LadeAufgabenByMitarbeiter((int)Daten.LadeAktuellenBenutzer()?.mitarbeiter.id, new Daten.Ziel<Aufgabe[]>(aufgabenGeladen));


            panel.Children.Add(aufgaben);




            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

.xaml

```
        <CalendarView Name="kalender" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedDatesChanged="kalender_SelectedDatesChanged"></CalendarView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to know that event "CalendarViewDayItemChanging" is called when CalendarView is loading:
[image]

This is official MSDN documentation:

[MSDN CalendarView documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.aspx#events)

To get the selected date and display ContentDialog you have to use "SelectedDatesChanged" event.

I have changed you code and now it should be like below in XAML:

**UPDATED:**

```
<CalendarView Name="kalender" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedDatesChanged="kalendar_SelectedDatesChanged"></CalendarView>
```

And the C# code:

```
private async void kalendar_SelectedDatesChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        dialog = new ContentDialog();
        dialog.Title = args.AddedDates[0].Date.ToString() + "    " + Daten.LadeAktuellenBenutzer()?.mitarbeiter.vorname + " " + Daten.LadeAktuellenBenutzer()?.mitarbeiter.name;
        dialog.MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth;

        panel = new StackPanel();

        aufgaben = new TextBlock();
        aufgaben.Text = "Sie haben an diesem Tag folgendes zu tun:\n";
        aufgaben.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;


        panel.Children.Add(aufgaben);

        await dialog.showAsync();
    }
```

Now you can get the date (also pick only day or month or year and display contect dialog). Remember to use "dialog.showAsync()" method.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. The eventname was a bit misleading.

Comment: But when I click the same date again. I get an error in the line with Dialog.title= etc. : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Let me check please once I get home ok?

Comment: Of Course :D No prob

Comment: I have updated XAML code - event should be (I have pasted old one - sorry):
SelectedDatesChanged="kalendar_SelectedDatesChanged"
If you still have a problem, please paste your C# code - I will go through it.

Comment: I ve done that already, but it keeps crashing when opening the same day twice, one by one. I have updated the Code, so this is the file. I think it could have something to do with the AddDates[0] and the back button press but I can´t figure this Thing out.

Comment: I do not see any code to dismiss the dialog (dialog.Hide())
Do you try to click back button when dialog is on the screen?

Comment: Yep, because a click outside does not make it hide.

Comment: Any idea? It still crashes when opening the same day twice.

Comment: I have added a Picture what happens when clicking the same day behind each other. When you open the first time you have to go back with the arrow on the top left Corner. Is there a way to do this by a simple click in the greyed out area

Comment: @omginput I have reproduced this error. It looks like there is a small bug unfortunately. I tried to do the same with "CalendarDatePicker" control and if I select the same date once again there is no data.
Please also see this post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/80a25651-8795-4730-9724-83e9f672ea72/uwpdeselecting-calendarview-date-throws-error-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still don´t know what to do in my case. I can deselect it but can´t select it once again. Also I can´t force the user to have >0 Dates selected. What do you mean with 'bug'? Microsoft Api side?

Comment: Any idea for a Workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have tried different aproaches but still no result... Once I got one I will of course let you know. :(

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way I´m looking for an element which Displays my data in a list so I can sort Things by click on the top column bar or search Things through a searchbar. Is it true that there is no element in UWP 10? ListView Shows me the Content in a list but it can´t sort it. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: There is no one simple element. How would you like to sort data in the ListView? Alphabetically?

Comment: Alphabetically and by DateTime object.

Comment: If you would like to sort by DateTime please refer to this post: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-datetime
To sort alphabetically refert to this one: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort
Search in the application depends on the UI you have created. You can do it in many different ways (for instance with ListView and TextBox).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I´ll use ListView which contains objects of self made element combination.